# 2007 Toyota Camry Shaking

Tags: toyota, camry, vibration

I have a 07 3.5 v6 with 213k miles on it. Recently the car started shaking when I got to about to about 60. I had been driving it for about 20 minutes and it didn't shake before at that speed. It seems to shift fine. When it starts doing that it keeps doing it even at lower speeds and then will be fine for a while. Would a CV joint going bad do something like this? I did notice a little bit of a clunking sound coming from the left front when driving on a gravel or bumpy road.

Comment: I'd suggest you check to see if one of your tires threw a weight. A CVJ doesn't usually give balance issues when it goes bad.

Comment: It seems like it would be more consistent if it were a tire weight.

Comment: No, a tire is almost never "in balance" ... the tire shop just balances it so that you don't feel it *most of the time*. They'll balance it up to 80mph or so and call it a day. If you lose a weight, it can throw it out of balance so it's only felt above a certain speed. It's about harmonics and such. Seriously, it's the first place I'd look if I were you.

Comment: Many times worn suspension parts particularly tie rod ends and\or ball joints can cause these symptoms. They can also clunk when hitting bumps.

Comment: Most of the time I can drive it up to 60 or 70 and it is smooth.  Intermittently if will start shaking really bad when reaching 60 and then continue at lower speeds.